# How to add text in an array using fs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, fs

I have a json array called "names" for a poll, I have already the input but I need to store the name inside the array "names" using fs, I have tried to search on google and stack overflow how to but nothing worked for me

Before

```
{
    "names": [
        "test",
        "test2"
    ],
    ...
}
```

After

```
{
    "names": [
        "test",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: `obj.names.push(name)`?

Comment: what do you mean `store the name inside the array "names" using fs`?

Answer (score -1):

```
let name_list = {
    "names": [
        "test",
        "test2"
    ]
}

function addName(name)
{
  arr_name = name_list.names
  arr_name.push(name)
}
addName('test3')
console.log(name_list);
```